# Stream mp3 file over aSynchronous server/client

Tags: c#

I have a server/client setup that uses aSynchronous sockets. Now i also want to stream a mp3 thats saved local on the server to the client. I've searched the forum but haven't found a solution yet. Could someone push me in the right direction?

If someone has a better option then the above feel free to comment :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should have some kind of server that can stream like Flash Media Server or Windows Media Services before you trying to stream a .mp3 file.

Comment: You didn't mention architecture in your question, so I've (probably incorrectly) assumed a WCF stance in my answer.  If you would prefer something different, drop a comment and I'll adjust my answer.  If you're using something selfhosted like a Windows Service/App w/o WCF, you can probably use [NetworkStreams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) and achieve the same thing as outlined in my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much answered your own question with the terms used.  ;-)

You can load the *.mp3's on the server into a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx).  With that in mind, you can probably guess and google the rest, streaming the mp3 will be no different to transferring any other file type.

There are a few complexities involved in transferring streams, so I strongly recommend you review the following couple links:

[MSDN Article on Large Data Transfers with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

[WCF Service File Transfer Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFDownloadUploadService.aspx)